# Python Pandas Dataframe loop iteration

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, iteration

```
import pandas as pd
import re

df1 = pd.DataFrame({"Greetings": ["Greetings to you too", "hi", "hello", "hey", "greetings", "sup", "what's up", "yo"]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"Farewell": ["GoodBye", "See you", "Bye", "Laters"]})

frames = [df1, df2]
df3=pd.concat(frames, axis=1, join='outer', copy=True)


sentence = 'hi'
for index, row in df3.iterrows():
   if index>0:
       if sentence.lower() in df3.iloc[index,:].values:
           print(df3.iloc[index].values)
```

This gives me an output of:

```
['hi' 'See you']
```

The end purpose is to basically iterate through all columns from 2nd row onwards to look for keyword match (which is why I put: if index>0) and if it finds a match, then to output by default the first item of that column (in this case "Greetings to you too" which is df3.iloc[0,0] in this scenario.

Hence I need help to add additional line of code, so that the result output after running the code will look like this:

```
"Greetings to you too"
```

Could someone help please.

Comment: Your description is very confusing.  Please provide an example of what you expect the results to look like.

Comment: I edited the post, hope it makes it more understandable. I just need the final output to show "Greetings to you too".

Comment: I don't undestand you

Comment: Change the last print  statement from `print(df3.iloc[index].values)` to `print(df3.iloc[:index].values)`, which will then print `[['Greetings to you too' 'GoodBye']]`. The issue is that df3.iloc first index operates on row where as the second one operates on column.

Comment: @prabhakar, that suggestion outputs the values for all rows at that index, what I need is to only output "Greetings to you too".

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer finally, the code just needed a tweak:

```
for index, row in df3.iterrows():
            if index>0:
                if sentence.lower() in df3.iloc[index,:].values:
                    print((df3.iloc[:index]).iloc[0,0])
```